# Is there an issue with CGColorGetComponents?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uicolor

When I call `CGColorGetComponents` with the `CGColor` returned from a `UIColor`, it seems to work properly *except* with white and black.

Here's the code...

```
CGColorRef myColorRef = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

const CGFloat * colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(myColorRef);

NSLog(@"r=%f, g=%f, b=%f, a=%f",
    colorComponents[0],
    colorComponents[1],
    colorComponents[2],
    colorComponents[3]);
```

This logs

```
r=1.000000, g=1.000000, b=0.000000, a=0.000000
```

Note both B and A are zero, not one.

If you substitute other colors like redColor, blueColor, etc., it works... the RGB and A values are set as one would expect.  But again, black and white produce odd results.  Is there some issue with this function or is there some workaround/task I should be doing?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`[UIColor whiteColor]` and `[UIColor blackColor]` use `[UIColor colorWithWhite:alpha:]` to create the UIColor. Which means this CGColorRef has only 2 color components, not 4 like colors created with `[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]`.

Of course you can NSLog those too.

```
if (CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(myColorRef) == 2) {
    const CGFloat *colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(myColorRef);
    NSLog(@"r=%f, g=%f, b=%f, a=%f", colorComponents[0], colorComponents[0], colorComponents[0], colorComponents[1]);
}
else if (CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(myColorRef) == 4) {
    const CGFloat * colorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(myColorRef);
    NSLog(@"r=%f, g=%f, b=%f, a=%f", colorComponents[0], colorComponents[1], colorComponents[2], colorComponents[3]);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"What is this?");
}
```

---

Be aware that there are different colorSpaces too. So if you need this code for more than logging (e.g. saving RGBA strings to json) you have to check (and probably convert) the colorSpace too.

Comment: Ok, so starting from a UIColor, how does one set the current fill and stroke colors easily, or do we have to do what you just did there every time we need to do this? (As for color spaces, I'm only interested in the RGBA values as set between 0.0 and 1.0 and displayed on the screen.  Anything else will be outside of the scope of what we are doing.)

Comment: for a CGContextRef? simply use `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);`

Comment: Also, what's `color.CGColor` in your code?  Is that different than `myColorRef`?

Comment: oh, sorry. Forgot to change that to your variable names. color is a UIColor. So color.CGColor is the same as your myColorRef

Comment: Aaah!  The whole reason we were getting the components was to call CGContextSetColor.  Didn't know about the 'WithColor' variant that basically does that for us.  I must've overlooked that.  Perfect!

Comment: Just as an aside, I take it in my original code, if CGColorGetComponents was only returning two values, when I accessed the third and fourth float (indexes 2 and 3) technically I was reading invalid memory there, correct?  If so, that could've been nasty!

Comment: Use `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);`

Comment: Very helpful, thanks for that @MatthiasBauch !! I just lost 2 hours understanding nothing about this yellow color I was getting instead of white <_<...