# Different behaviours for different colors in drawRect:

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect, cgcontextref

I am puzzled by the way the following code works.
It is expected to produce a black disk surrounded by a colored circle.
It works fine with certain colors (as explained in the comments), but not with some others.
Can anyone explain this misterious behaviour?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect rectangle; CGFloat shiftVal=2.0,lineWidth=3.0;
    rectangle.origin=CGPointMake(shiftVal, shiftVal);
    rectangle.size=self.frame.size;
    rectangle.size.width-=shiftVal*2;
    rectangle.size.height-=shiftVal*2;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);

    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents([UIColor greenColor].CGColor); // Works as expected.
    //const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents([UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor); // No surrounding circle (instead of darkGray).
    //const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents([UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor); // Produces a greenish circle (instead of lightGray)
    // Draw the outer circle:
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,
                               components[0],
                               components[1],
                               components[2],
                               components[3]);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
}
```

Comment: before taking a deeper look into this - you know what is a good idea if something does not *look* as expected? Images!!! 2 or 3 screenshots would be perfect.

Comment: Replace the call to `CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor` with one simple line: `[[UIColor someColor] setStroke];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238743/is-there-an-issue-with-cgcolorgetcomponents) I am guessing that `darkGrayColor` and `lightGrayColor` both represent gray-sacle values rather tan rgba-values. And therefore dont have 4 comoponents but only 2.

You might want / have to use a different approach of setting the color:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed misunderstanding how CGColorGetComponents works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
CGColorGetComponents([UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
```

does **not** return the RGB values of 'light gray'. If you inspect its values in the debugger, you  will see that it is an array of `0.6667, 1, 0, 0`. These are the components in a [gray-only color space](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColorSpace/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray).

You should use another function like [`CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor) or [`UIColor`'s `setStroke` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/setStroke) to set the color. They have the additional benefit of being shorter as well :)