# Draw and fill custom shapes

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath

I have a UIImageView that houses the picture of a floorplan.  On top of that I have a UIView where I would like to draw custom shapes (semi-transparently) over different rooms on the floor plan.

I read about UIBeizerPaths for drawing custom shapes, but wasn't able to find out if I could then fill the shape I had drawn.

Summary:

1)  Can I fill shapes with color that are drawn from UIBeizerPaths?

2)  IF yes, can it be semi-transparent?

3)  Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to:

1. Override `drawRect` (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589265/how-to-draw-a-custom-uiview-that-is-just-a-circle-iphone-app))
2. Call `CGContextDrawPath` (see the API [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html))

And yes, you should be able to use a semi-transparent color.