# How to make a round WKInterfaceButton in watchkit?

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2, wkinterfacebutton

iOS can use `layer.cornerRadius` to make a round `UIButton`.

Does `WKInterfaceButton` have this property?

If not, how can I make a round `WKInterfaceButton` in `WatchKit`.

Comment: You'll need to set the background image of the WKInterfaceButton to a round graphic.

Answer (score 11):

If you put an image inside a group, you can then set the radius of the group. This crops the image into a circle. In the picture below, I have:

- Group (radius 56)

  - Group (radius 52)

    - Image (a square image)

[image: Watch Screenshot]

While this example is with an image, you can use the same technique for a button. Previously the dog was clickable as a button so this is doable.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This is the cleanest and easiest one without needing any custom drawing or adding any static image to the project. And yes, I can confirm that this does indeed work with buttons, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`WKInterfaceButton` does not have a corner radius property. You can make a circular button by setting a circular image as the button's background image. You can generate the image in code doing something like this: [Draw a simple circle uiimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116472/draw-a-simple-circle-uiimage)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an image to make WKInterfaceButton rounded. Instead:

1. Go to **Attributes inspector** for the button, and select content type: *Group*
   [image: WKInterfaceButton Attributes inspector. Content type selection]
2. Inside the button find the group and set its *corner radius* to whatever you need.
3. Scroll down the inspector and set both fixed *Width* and *Height* to the value equal to the radius doubled. Here you go
   [image: WKInterfaceGroup settings in the Attributes Inspector. Width and Height.]

You can put whatever you want inside the button, for example a text label. This way you also can make oval buttons.