# Add Border to circular UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiimage

I have been looking at many stack overflow posts but none have them have been able to give me my desired solution. So far I have been able to get an image and convert it into a circle using AlamoFire. However, unfortunately alamo fire does not provide an option to add a border to a UIImage. I was wondering if anyone had a solution to my problem. Here is my code for making the image into a circle:

```
if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

   let markerImage = downloadedImage
   let markerImageSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
   let markerImageFilter = AspectScaledToFillSizeCircleFilter(size: markerImageSize)

   let finalMarkerImage = markerImageFilter.filter(markerImage)

   marker.icon = finalMarkerImage
}
```

As you can see I am able to get a circle but not one with a border. So far I have tried many stack overflow post solutions to try and work with my AlamoFire solution. Here are some of the posts:
[Making a UIImage to a circle form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399343/making-a-uiimage-to-a-circle-form)

[Cut a UIImage into a circle Swift(iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046571/cut-a-uiimage-into-a-circle-swiftios)

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Show a picture of what you want as an end result. Makes it a *lot* easier to try and help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116472/draw-a-simple-circle-uiimage ? You want to modify the image, or just render it in your app?

Comment: @DonMag I have just added a picture of what I have and what I want.

Comment: @Larme I would ideally simply like to make the image into a circle with a border.

Comment: Just set your `UIImageView`'s corner radius and it's `layer.borderColor`

Comment: @AshleyMills Well thats the whole problem. The image is a UIImage not a UIImageView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding UIImage and adding a border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984966/rounding-uiimage-and-adding-a-border)

Comment: @Larme, I disagree becuase none of those solutions worked for me

Comment: I assume that the image will be embed in imageview, right?

Comment: The Image is not put in an image view it is set as a google maps marker icon which requires a value of an UIImage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you should apply the required appearance to the *UIImageView* that contains your UIImage, as follows:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.brown.cgColor
```

**Update:**

Since you are working with Google Maps (`GMSMarker`), you should create an UIImageView programmatically (apply the above code snippet to it) and add it to your marker as [`iconView`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#use_the_markers_iconview_property), as follows:

```
marker.iconView = imageView
```

So, it should be similar to:

```
// of course the values of the width/height (size) is up to you
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

// set your image
imageView.image = ...

marker.iconView = imageView
```

Comment: yes, I have tried this but the problem is that I can't add a UIImageView to my marker.icon value as the value has to be a UIImage.

Comment: Yes, I am using google maps, and yes I am using GMSMarker

Comment: Are are able to add a `UIImageView` to the marker, check the update :)

Comment: I tried doing so but I am right now working through this error: constant imageView is used before initialized

Comment: Thank You SO MUCH!!! Have been searching for a solution like this for a long time. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 6):

This should create round image with white border…

```
func round(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let imageWidth = image.size.width
    let imageHeight = image.size.height

    let diameter = min(imageWidth, imageHeight)
    let isLandscape = imageWidth > imageHeight

    let xOffset = isLandscape ? (imageWidth - diameter) / 2 : 0
    let yOffset = isLandscape ? 0 : (imageHeight - diameter) / 2

    let imageSize = CGSize(width: diameter, height: diameter)

    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageSize).image { _ in

        let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imageSize))
        ovalPath.addClip()
        image.draw(at: CGPoint(x: -xOffset, y: -yOffset))
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        ovalPath.lineWidth = diameter / 50
        ovalPath.stroke()
    }
}
```

Then

```
let roundImage = round(image: downloadedImage)
```

[image]

Comment: I know what I am about to ask is probably obvious but can you explain how I would use implement your solution in my code with my variable of downloadedImage

Comment: It's a nice sunny day here, so I've updated my answer, but really, you need to try and figure some of this stuff out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

for people struggling with the obj-c version of @ashley answer. Same logic

```c
+ (UIImage *)drawBorderToImage:(UIImage *)image withColor:(UIColor *)color andThickness:(CGFloat)thickness {
    CGFloat diameter = MIN(image.size.width, image.size.height);
    BOOL isLandscape = image.size.width > image.size.height;
    CGFloat xOffset = isLandscape ? (image.size.width - diameter) / 2 : 0;
    CGFloat yOffset = isLandscape ? 0 : (image.size.height - diameter) / 2;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(diameter, diameter);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    UIBezierPath *ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
    [ovalPath addClip];
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-xOffset, -yOffset)];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    ovalPath.lineWidth = thickness;
    [ovalPath stroke];
    UIImage *borderedImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return borderedImage;
}
```