# Creating 100% round UIView/UIImageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I intend to use the following lines of code to add a "round view":

```
_myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
_myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithR:153 G:85 B:57 alpha:1.0];
_myBackView.layer.cornerRadius = artworkViewWidth / 2;
_myBackView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
_myBackView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
_myBackView.clipsToBounds = NO;
[self.view addSubview:_myBackView];
```

The view is created fine and seems mostly round. But the problem is it does not seems to be "100% round" - the four edges seems to be a bit clipped still, although I had the clipsToBounds property set to NO.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

**EDIT**: just added the repro picture. Please pay attention to the 4 edges which were clipped. [image: repro picture]

Comment: Would help to have the image you are testing with. Also, is the image a square?

Comment: Please include the computation for `rect`.  That rect must have `width==artworkViewWidth` for the corner radius to be correct.  If it does, the view will form a perfect circle.

Comment: @CodeBender thanks for the response. I've included the screen shot. I'm not directly displaying an image here yet, but just testing the cornerRadius stuff with a UIView directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (use a circle png mask layer)

```
- (void)useMaskFor: (UIView*)colorArea {

    CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = colorArea.bounds;
    UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cirMask.png"];
    maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id)maskImage.CGImage;
    colorArea.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Answered from this [How to draw a custom UIView that is just a circle - iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589265/how-to-draw-a-custom-uiview-that-is-just-a-circle-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

```
 _image.layer.cornerRadius = _image.frame.size.height/2;

 _image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

try the code above.